# C getopt multiple value

Tags: c, input, getopt

My argument is like this

```
./a.out -i file1 file2 file3
```

How can I utilize `getopt()` to get 3 (or more) input files? 
I'm doing something like this:

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:xyz.."))!= -1){
  case 'i':
     input = optarg; 
     break;
  ...
}
```

I get just the `file1`; how to get `file2`, `file3`?

Comment: Note that the question [Supplying two arguments to command line option using `getopt()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559391/supplying-two-arguments-to-command-line-option-using-getopt/) provides some possibilities not mentioned here.

Comment: The answers below that tweak `optind` in the program code are treading on thin ice.  There is no documented requirement that `getopt()` behave if you modify `optind` or `optarg` in the calling code. Granted, most current and plausible implementations will not have a problem, but a hypothetical implementation could record its internal state in non-global variables, and simply set the globals as it returns.  Such an implementation would meet the POSIX specification for [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html), but the tinkering shown would not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you must, you could start at `argv[optind]` and increment `optind` yourself.  However, I would recommend against this since I consider that syntax to be poor form. (How would you know when you've reached the end of the list?  What if someone has a file named with a `-` as the first character?)

I think that it would be better yet to change your syntax to either:

```
/a.out -i file1 -i file2 -i file3
```

Or to treat the list of files as positional parameters:

```
/a.out file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Thanks jamesdlin I will look at [optind] as I have quite many arguments other than -i

Answer (score 31):

I know this is quite old but I came across this in my search for a solution.

```
while((command = getopt(argc, argv, "a:")) != -1){

    switch(command){
        case 'a':

        (...)

        optind--;
        for( ;optind < argc && *argv[optind] != '-'; optind++){
              DoSomething( argv[optind] );         
        }

        break;
    }
```

I found that *int optind* (extern used by *getopt()* ) points to next position after the 'current *argv*' selected by *getopt()*;
That's why I decrease it at the beginning.

First of all *for loop* checks if the value of current argument is within boundaries of *argv* (*argc* is the length of array so last position in array argv is *argc-1*).
Second part of *&&* compares if the next argument's first char is '-'. If the first char is '-' then we run out of next values for current argument else argv[optind] is our next value. And so on until the argv is over or argument runs out of values.

At the end increment *optind* to check for the next argv.

Note that because we are checking '*optind < argc*' first second part of condition will not be executed unless first part is true so no worries of reading outside of array boundaries.

PS I am a quite new C programmer if someone has an improvements or critique please share it.

Comment: This is pretty old, but I thought I might add one critique. Not only should you check for the '-', but also make sure that `strlen(argv[optind])` is equal to 2. This would make sure that the it will properly handle parameters that start with a dash. This code was helpful to me though! +1

Comment: You're referring to parameters like `-whatever` right @TheBat ? I got confused because what you state wouldn't work for `getopt_long`.

Answer (score 6):

Note that glibc's nonconformant argument permutation extension will break any attempt to use multiple arguments to `-i` in this manner. And on non-GNU systems, the "second argument to `-i`" will be interpreted as the first non-option argument, halting any further option parsing. With these issues in mind, I would drop `getopt` and write your own command line parser if you want to use this syntax, since it's not a syntax supported by `getopt`.

Answer (score 6):

I looked and tried the code above, but I found my solution a little easier and worked better for me:

The handling I wanted was:

```
-m mux_i2c_group mux_i2c_out
```

(2 arguments required).

Here's how it panned out for me:

```
case 'm':
    mux_i2c_group = strtol(optarg, &ch_p, 0);

    if (optind < argc && *argv[optind] != '-'){
        mux_i2c_out = strtol(argv[optind], NULL, 0);
        optind++;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n-m option require TWO arguments <mux_group> "
                        "<mux_out>\n\n");
        usage();
    }

    use_mux_flag = 1;
    break;
```

This grabbed the first value form me as normal and then just looked for the second, REQUIRED value.

Comment: nice decision! Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

The solution by GoTTimw has proven very useful to me. However, I would like to mention one more idea, that has not been suggested here yet.

Pass arguments as one string in this way.

```
./a.out -i "file1 file2 file3"
```

Then you get one string as a single argument and you only need to split it by space.