# Supplying two arguments to command line option using getopt

Tags: c, getopt

Is there an alternative way to pass two arguments to an option as a single string when using `getopt()`? Normally I would do the following:

```
./command -o "key value" [command arguments]
```

Then I would have to split the argument string explicitly:

```
 while ((op = getopt(argc, argv, "o:")) != EOF) {
    switch (op) {
             case 'o': 
                 char* result = NULL;
                 result = strtok_r(optarg," ");
                 while(result) {
                     /* DO STUFF */
                     result = strtok(NULL," ");
                 }

                 break;
             default:
                 printUsage()
                 break;
   }
```

So, I am wondering if it is possible to use the following and make `getopt()` treat "value" as `-o` second argument rather than the command argument?

```
./command -o key value [command arguments]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The POSIX standard [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) does not support multiple arguments for a single flag letter.  There are a couple of options available to you.

One option is to specify the names as arguments to separate option letters (or use the same one twice):

```
./command -o key -v value
./command -o key -o value
```

Another option is to use the POSIX standard [`getsubopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsubopt.html) and a command line notation such as:

```
./command -o key=value
```

This works pretty well for your shown scenario if the set of keys is relatively small (not so well if they are large, but you could do without `getsubopt()` then and simply parse `optarg` for the `=` yourself.

Another option is to write a command line parser that will accept multiple arguments as you require.  I wrote one to be able to parse the diverse and ill-disciplined argument handling on programs that we use at work - and it is not dreadfully difficult (though it wasn't altogether easy, either).  It specifically has to handle N (N > 1) option values after a single flag.  Contact me (see my profile) if you want to look at the source.  There are some tricky issues to resolve, such as what happens if you expect 3 names after the option letter, but one of the first three arguments starts with a dash `-`, or `--` appears.  I only allow a fixed number of arguments, not a variable number, but that is in part because my use cases didn't need to cover a variable number (and it doesn't sound as if yours would, either).

Answer (score 1):

How would `getopt` know where your `-o` options end, and where your `command arguments` start?

One simple workaround is to use to `-o` specifiers:

```
$ cat t.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char op;
    while ((op = getopt(argc, argv, "o:")) != EOF) {
        switch (op) {
            case 'o':
                printf("Option: %s\n", optarg);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
$ gcc t.c
$ ./a.out -o one -o two -o three
Option: one
Option: two
Option: three
```

Comment: I know this workaround, but since the two option arguments are bound together (key value pair), I cannot split them up

Comment: The use two switches `-ok key -ov val` and add a bit of logic to make sure they are specified in the right order. Or see other options in the previous question I linked.