# Php get multiple files passed to getopt(), *.jpg

Tags: php, command-line, getopt

I am using getopt() to get php command line arguments.  I want to collect a list of files or directories using the *.

Example

in

```
/my/dir/file1.jpg
/my/dir/file2.jpg
/my/dir/file3.jpg
```

I would like:

```
$ ./myscript.php -s *.jpg
```

for optarg[s], I would like to get an return an array containing:

```
array(file1.jpg, file2.jpg, file3.jpg)
```

I've searched for a solution but all I can manage to get back is the first match.

Comment: Which platform are you running on Windows and *nix have very different behaviors for *.xxx

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3939232/49879